# Highlight first empty row after table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in which user is supposed to add names. This table is then used for a dynamic drop-down data validation list. I want to visually remind the user to add the text to the first empty row (table has only one column) - just after the table end so the table can automatically expand. Which formula can I use with conditional formatting to highlight the row to input? (I don't want to use VBA.)
Help appreciated.

Comment: `IF(COUNTA(current:last) = 0, !ISEMPTY(previous))`

Comment: Better you create Dynamic Named Range, will automatically expands as soon you add new values,, otherwise to automate VBA is best option!